# Add console log in an one arrow (auto return) function without adding curly braces

Tags: javascript, console.log, arrow-functions

So consider you have a one line auto return arrow function:

```
const test = (val) => val;
```

How would you check the `val` without doing:

```
const test = (val) => {
  console.log(val);
  return val;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `||` between the arrow function and the returned value like so:

```
const test = (val) => console.log(val) || val;
```

This will not interfere with the process and will also log `val` without the hassle of adding `{}` and `return` and undoing it once you're done

Comment: Yes, this will work as `console.log(val)` will return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is a great function for this -

```js
const echo = (x) =>
  ( console.log(x)
  , x
  )

const test = x => echo(x) + 1

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

const result = arr.map(test)

console.log(result)
```

Arrow functions are a functional style. Utilising functional techniques will make it more enjoyable to work with arrow expressions -

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f(x), x)
  
const echo =
 effect(console.log)
  
const test = x => echo(x + 1) // <-- wrap echo around anything

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

const result = arr.map(test)

console.log(result)

// 2
// 3
// 4
// [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

You can use `echof` to wrap an entire function, such as `echof(test)` -

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f(x), x)

const comp = (f, g) =>
  x => f(g(x))

const echo =
 effect(console.log)

const echof = f =>
  comp(echo, f)

const test = x => x * x

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

const result = arr.map(echof(test)) // <-- echof

console.log(result)
// 1
// 4
// 9
// [ 1, 4, 9 ]
```